# Notepad++ Regex Search XML argument for anything but certain word

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I have a well structured XML file with several grouped units, which contain a consistent number of child elements.

I am trying to find a way, through Regex in Notepad++, to search throughout all of these groups for a certain argument that contains a single word. I have found a way of doing this but the problem is I want to find the negation of this word, that means for instance, if the word is "*downward*" I want to find anything that is **NOT** "*downward*".

Here is an example:

```
<xml:jus id="84" trek="spanned" place="downward">
```

I've came up with `<xml:jus id="\d+" trek="[\w]*" place="\<downward">` to find these tags, but I need to find all other matches that do not have "*downward*" in `place=` argument. I tried `<xml:jus id="\d+" trek="[\w]*" place="^\<downward">` but without success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a negative lookahead to exclude `downward` from being the place:

```regex
<[^>]+ place="(?!downward").*?"[^>]*>
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

If the properties and the string is in the same format, you could also make use of [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to first match what you want to exclude.

```
<xml:jus id="\d+" trek="\w+" place="downward">(*SKIP)(*F)|<xml:jus id="\d+" trek="\w+" place="[^"]+">
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UGA6ly/1)

Comment: Great, this seems to work flawlessly, thanks. Just one more thing. Lets say that I want to replace everything that is not "downward" by "downward". How would I go about replacing it?

Comment: @PedroSousa In that case you can use `<xml:jus id="\d+" trek="\w+" place="(?!downward)\K[^"]+(?="[^<>]*>)` https://regex101.com/r/YEgFCC/1